# My WPF custom control's Data Context is superseding parent's

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datacontext

In my main window, I try to bind to a `bool`, but it's looking in my custom control's `DataContext` instead. If I don't assign `DataContext` in the user control, then the main window's bindings works, but (obviously) this brakes the bindings in the user control.

Here's the error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyControlVisible' property not found on 'object' ''MyUserControlModel' (HashCode=1453241)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyControlVisible; DataItem='MyUserControlModel' (HashCode=1453241); target element is 'MyUserControl' (Name='_myUserControl'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

I need binding to work on both controls, but I don't want the user control's `DataContext` to supersede the window's.

Here's the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Sandbox.Controls" Title="Sandbox">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Controls:MyUserControl x:Name="_myUserControl" Visibility="{Binding MyControlVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

namespace Sandbox
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private MainWindowModel model;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = model = new MainWindowModel();
            _myUserControl.Initialize(model.MyUControlModel);
        }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel;
using Sandbox.Controls;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class MainWindowModel : BaseModel
    {
        public MyUserControlModel MyUControlModel { get; set; }
        public bool MyControlVisible { get; set; }
        public MainWindowModel()
        {
            MyUControlModel = new MyUserControlModel();
            MyControlVisible = false;
            OnChange("");
        }
    }

    public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnChange(string s)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
            }
        }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="Sandbox.Controls.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBoundText}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

namespace Sandbox.Controls
{
    public partial class MyUserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Initialize(MyUserControlModel context)
        {
            DataContext = context;
        }
    }

}

namespace Sandbox.Controls
{
    public class MyUserControlModel : BaseModel
    {
        public string MyBoundText { get; set; }
        public MyUserControlModel()
        {
            MyBoundText = "Hello World!";
            OnChange("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is one of the many reasons you should never set the `DataContext` directly from the `UserControl` itself.

When you do so, you can no longer use any other `DataContext` with it because the UserControl's `DataContext` is hardcoded in.

In the case of your binding, normally the `DataContext` would be inherited so the `Visibility` binding could find the property `MyControlVisible` on the current `DataContext`, however because you hardcoded the `DataContext` in your UserControl's constructor, that property is not found.

You could specify a different binding source in your binding, such as

```
<Controls:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
    Path=DataContext.MyControlVisible, 
    Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}" ... />
```

However that's just a workaround for the problem for this specific case, and in my view is not a permanent solution. A better solution is to simply not hardcode the `DataContext` in your `UserControl`

There are a few different ways you can do depending on your UserControl's purpose and how your application is designed.

- You could create a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) on your UserControl to pass in the value, and bind to that.

  ```
  <Controls:MyUserControl UcModel="{Binding MyUControlModelProperty}" ... />
  ```

  and

  ```
  <UserControl x:Class="Sandbox.Controls.MyUserControl"
               ElementName=MyUserControl...>
      <Grid DataContext="{Binding UCModel, ElementName=MyUserControl}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBoundText}"/>
      </Grid>
  </UserControl>
  ```
- Or you could build your `UserControl` with the expectation that a specific property will get passed to it in the `DataContext`. This is normally what I do, in combination with `DataTemplates`.

  ```
  <Controls:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding MyUControlModelProperty}" ... />
  ```

  and

  ```
  <UserControl x:Class="Sandbox.Controls.MyUserControl"...>
      <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBoundText}"/>
      </Grid>
  </UserControl>
  ```
- As I said above, I like to use `DataTemplates` to display my `UserControls` that expect a specific type of `Model` for their `DataContext`, so typically my XAML for the main window would look something like this:

  ```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyUControlModel}">
      <Controls:MyUserControl />
  </DataTemplate>

  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyUControlModelProperty}" ... />
  ```